# How do I find the coordinates of nan values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried `np.where` but without success:

```
>>>a = np.array([np.nan, 1])
>>>np.where(a == np.nan)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
np.where(a == np.nan)
```

to

```
np.where(np.isnan(a))
```

NaN values always return false in equality checks, even with another NaN value. So you need to use special functions to check for NaN like np.isnan.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,-1,1,np.nan, 0, 1, np.nan])
print np.where(np.isnan(x))
```

Returns:

```
(array([4, 7]),)
```